# Blaupunkt 4k LED TV as external monitor for MBP mid 2012 retina issue

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I initially connected the MBP 2012 retina 2.7 GHZ to the 4k display it showed me 3840x2160 correctly. But when I was optimising some display settings I changed to 1080p after that I no longer get the 3840x2160 option at all.Yet I could still load into my Windows with the 4k at 30 hz. It would be great to know how can get the 3840x2160 resolution option back.

It would be interesting if anyone could tell me if they have successfully shot upon 4K with 60 hz on mid MCP retina. If so would be great to know how you accomplished it.

Comment: My guess is you'll have to change the refresh rate down to 30 before it will show you the higher resolution. Whether you can do that in system prefs or have to get hold of SwitchResX, idk.

Comment: I have already tried using SwitchResX but no success. I also tried to change the refresh rate. But it doesnt help !

Answer (score 1):

Your system supports following resolutions:

You can use 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs at the following resolutions and refresh rates via the built-in HDMI port.

```
3840 x 2160 at 30 Hz refresh rate

4096 x 2160 at 24 Hz refresh rate (mirroring is not supported at this resolution)- MBP 2013 and up.
```

Thus no 60Hz is possible.

Comment: But suddenly I am not able to run even in 3840x2160 at 30 hz.Which was working fine in yosemite. It vanished after I changed to 1080p 60 Hz I can't see the 4k at 30 hz anymore. But the option is still active in my windows partition. I am not sure how to get 3840x2160 at 30 hz back

Comment: hold the option key (alt) before selecting the Display Scaled to see all options

Comment: yes I did try it even in that I get only maximum upto 1080p 60 hz

Comment: Its very strange that I tried to reset the PR also change many other parameters unfortunately no luck. Will complete reinstall of the OS solve the issue?

Comment: ok, lets try the ColorSync Utility in your utility folder and see if you can change it there before anything major.

Comment: I could see only color profile changeability in it. Nothing else. I don't think ColorSync Utility has any help for us in this aspect.